# Debug aspx / cs scripts with no VS2017 project

Tags: asp.net

Someone's handed me a crashing aspx / .cs script to debug.

Any idea how to set up a VS2017 project to debug it?

I've tried using the wizard, Visual C#, asp.net

This works OK for one set of pages on the site, Default.aspx and Default.aspc.cs

When I add the page I want to debug I get loads of compilation errors in the cs file, referring to objects in the aspx

```
The name 'Chart1' does not exist in the current context
```

and one reference I can't see how to sort out

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'Package' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: There is a high probability that that page is using code that exists elsewhere in the original solution. Your best bet to debugging would be to have access to that entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

VS2017 - File -> Open -> Website

browse to your local source folder and press OK

Right click on the aspx you want to debug. Choose 'Set As Start Page'

Now run the project.